# Easy way to convert JSON to pyarrow schema

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

Disclaimer: I'm new to apache parquet and pyarrow.  Is there is easy way to convert json to a pyarrow schema?  The json I'm working with is:

```
{
  "_time": ${datetime},
  "activity": ${event_id},
  "activity_id": 6,
  "category_name": "Network Activity", 
  "category_uid": 4,
  "class_name": "HTTP Activity", 
  "class_uid": 4002,
  "dst_endpoint": {
    "ip": ${sip}
  },
  "http_request": {
    "hostname": ${host},
      "url": {
        "hostname": ${url_host},
        "path": ${url_path},
        "text": ${url}
      },
    "user_agent": ${ua},
    "version": ${reqversion}
  },
  "http_response": {
    "code": ${respcode}
  },
  "metadata": {
    "version": 1.0.0
  },
  "severity": ${riskscore},
  "severity_id": 0,
  "src_endpoint": {
    "ip": ${cip}
  },
  "type_name": "HTTP Activity: Traffic",
  "type_uid": 400206
}
```

Comment: Check this https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Schema.html

Comment: any new for this question?